# Download pictures in modal ONLY when modal is displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Okay, so I want to have a LOT of buttons on a page, which each open a different modal, populated with a gif with php. As you may have guesse, downloading a lot of quite big gifs takes a ton of time.
Solution: load the gifs only when the modal containing them is actually displayed. I was advised to use the following jQuery snippet:

```
echo '<script>' . "\r\n";
echo '$("#btn_'.$id.'").click(function(){' . "\r\n";
echo '$("#img_'.$id.'").attr("src", "'.$id.".gif" . '"); });';
echo '</script>' . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
```

More readable clean, PHP-free version:

```
<script>
$("#btn_id").click(function(){
$("#img_id").attr("src", "id.gif"); });
</script>
```

The id is replaced with an actual id in php of course.

Now this snippet doesn't actually PULL the gif from the server, so in the end nothing gets displayed at all...

edit: more code

```
<button id="img_id" class="modalbutton" style="background-image: url(thumbs/id.gif); cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('modal_id').style.display='block'"></button>
<div id="modal_id" class="w3-modal w3-animate-zoom" onclick="this.style.display = 'none'">
<span id="span_id" class="w3-closebtn w3-hover-red w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content" onclick="this.style.display='none'"><img id="img_id" src=""></div>
</div>
<script>
$("#btn_id").click(function(){
$("#img_id").attr("src", "id.gif"); });</script>
```

[Demo](http://traxxlab.traxx.li/test.html)

Comment: I would suggest using a single modal and then altering the src of the gif in that one modal - creating a modal for each gif would be bad. Far better to have a common modal that accommodates each different gif.

Comment: @gavgrif You are right but this doesn't solve the problem, that the browser doesn't seem to pull the images.

Comment: If image not displayed then path is probably wrong

Comment: @charlietfl The path is right but after checking the source in Firefox I see that the path doesnt get appended. I updated the question to show more of my code. Could it be that the source view doesn't get updated after jquery changes it?

Comment: depends what you mean by `check source`. If you mean looking at "View source" that is only what gets sent from server. Need to inspect live html in browser dev tools

Comment: @charlietfl After getting a live view of my html I can say: the source doesn't get set at all. Any idea of whats the problem?

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(event){
        var $id = event.target.id;
        document.getElementById('modal_'+$id).style.display='block';
        var $image = $('#img_'+$id);
        var $downloadingImage = $('#imagehelper_'+$id);
        $downloadingImage.attr('src', $id+'.gif');
        $downloadingImage.on('load', function() {
            $image.attr('src', $id+'.gif');
        }).each(function() {
            if(this.complete) $(this).load();
        });
    });
});
```

The script gets the id of the calling element, so I don't need a lot of different snippets.